# Img tag used in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

In a Laravel 5 project img tag is not working. I tried the src like -
`src="{{URL::asset('images/users/<?php echo Auth::user()->image_large; ?>')}}"`
- also tried - `src="{{URL::asset('images/users/{{Auth::user()->image_large}}')}}"` - but not working. Can anybody please help ?

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: in consol - the error is showing - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put an echo inside an echo. Once you're in a `{{ }}` block, you don't need another set of curly braces or an echo statement.

Instead do this:

```
{{ URL::asset('images/users/'. Auth::user()->image_large) }}
```

If that doesn't work, you have some other problem related to your path, or in the user model's image attribute.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you. It's working perfectly.